# deadlock cause by the exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, thread-safety

I have the following thread:

```
require 'thread'

myqueue = Queue.new

Thread.new do
  loop do
    a = Users.find(id)
    myqueue << a
  end
end

loop do
  user = myqueue.pop
  puts user.class
end
```

Deadlock is caused because Users was not loaded. How do I catch/rescue such exception?

Comment: Do you really have plural name for your model? Isn't it just a typo in code? As for me correct syntax should be `a = User.find(id)`

Comment: :) Yes I do, for the testing purposes

Comment: That's ok than. You can use begin, rescue, ensure and end blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

You have to wrap rescue inside the loop:

```
require 'thread'

myqueue = Queue.new

Thread.new do
  loop do
    begin
      a = Users.find(id)
      myqueue << a
    rescue Exception => e
      puts e.message
    end
  end
end

loop do
  user = myqueue.pop
  puts user.class
end
```